# Finding the passed number and percentage using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate

I have a exam table where it have details such as total (number of students attended the exam), failed (number of students failed in the exam) and the date like as shown below

```
id key    value date
 1 total    400 2017-02-28
 2 failed   200 2017-02-28
 3 total    350 2017-02-27
 4 failed   180 2017-02-27
 5 total    500 2017-02-26
 6 failed   250 2017-02-26 
 7 total    600 2017-02-25 
 8 failed   200 2017-02-25
 9 total    400 2017-02-24 
10 failed   100 2017-02-24
```

I have written many aggregate queries in MySQL but now I got a requirement for to bring a result like as shown below using a single query.

How can we calculate the passed and the passed percentage from two rows?

```
id total failed passed passed percentage date
 1   400    200    200 50%               2017-02-28 
 2   350    180    170 48.57%            2017-02-27
 3   500    250    250 50%               2017-02-26
 4   600    200    400 66.67%            2017-02-25
 5   400    100    200 75%               2017-02-24
```

Can anyone please help me on this

Comment: Edit your question and include your attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E.g.:

```
SELECT date
     , SUM(CASE WHEN attribute = 'total'  THEN value END) total
     , SUM(CASE WHEN attribute = 'failed' THEN value END) failed
     , SUM(CASE WHEN attribute = 'total'  THEN value END) - SUM(CASE WHEN attribute = 'failed' THEN value END) passed 
     , 100 - SUM(CASE WHEN attribute = 'failed' THEN value END) / SUM(CASE WHEN attribute = 'total' THEN value END) * 100 pct_passed
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY date;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `date` ties the rows together, you can use aggregation:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as id, total, failed, (total - failed) as passed,
       (1 - failed / total) as passed_rate
from (select , date,
             sum(case when key in ('total') then value else 0 end) as total,
             sum(case when key = 'failed' then value else 0 end) as failed
      from t
      group by date
     ) t cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params
order by date;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am getting exception, since I dont have `passed `under `key` column

Comment: @AlexMan . . . I don't know why I thought the values were for "passed" and "failed" rather than "total" and "failed".  I think the above formulation using a subquery fixes the issues.